# How to receive a string of sentences using click.option() in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, python-click

I am trying to create a simple command line interface to maintain to-do tasks.
I know that I can use `click.argument()` to get a string sentence from user but I want to have similar functionality using `click.option()`.

```
@click.command()
@click.option('-a', '--add', type=click.STRING, help='Task you want to add')
@click.option('-rm', '--remove', type=click.INT, help='ID of task you want to remove')
def cli(add, remove):
    if add:
        add_task(add)
    elif remove:
        remove_task(remove)
    else:
        list()
```

As per the above script:
`todo -a Hello World !!`
Only gets the string "Hello", however I want the complete sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the docs, all you need to do is add `nargs=<the number you want>` for example:

`@click.option('-a', '--add',nargs=2, type=click.STRING, help='Task you want to add')`

or you can always run you script like that:

`todo --add="Hello World !!"`

Comment: But to specify `nargs` I need to know the number of string words beforehand.This is not my use case. I want to receive string of any word length.

Comment: so use the second option i suggested

Comment: Okay, I will use that, but isn't there a  way to use `-a  STRING`  as it looks clean?

Comment: I can check in a few minutes, and get back to you, but if the second option solved your problem please upvote and accept :)

Comment: While using in the command line, click seems to be reading in the '='.
`todo --add "Hello World!!"`
Seems to fix this issue